# Using variable arguments when newing

Tags: javascript, new-operator, apply

I have a list of arguments such as `var args = ['blah', 1, 3.9]` and I want to apply it to something that needs to be newed like `new bleh.Thinggy(a, b, c)`.

I want to do the following `var m = {}; bleh.Thinggy.apply(m, args);`

I am worried there is something I am not thinking of does anyone know if this is safe?

Comment: Do you have any sources to back that up?

Comment: Apply is safe,but it would not return any instance of bleh.Thinggy

Comment: @Rene: You've got to be kidding me. I've been further even more decided to use even go need to do look more as anyone can.

Comment: @megazord pointy counts as a source. +1 for newing.

Comment: @Pointy What if that Contructor uses inheritance? Someone mentioned it could break, is that correct?

Comment: Hmm that's a good point - I'm not sure there's a way to do this that doesn't involve the constructor *knowing* it may be invoked this way. At least it can behave such that a no-argument call will not cause an exception or unwanted side-effect, so that your code can construct a new empty object and then use that as the first argument to `.apply()`.

Comment: @megazord it was a lord of the rings reference. Couldn't resist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current method is flawed, because prototype inheritance will not work as expected.
The equivalent of `method.apply(context, args)` for constructors is:

```
// Given a list of arguments `args`:
var bindArgs = [Constructor.prototype].concat(args);
new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Constructor, bindArgs));
```

The roles of [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) are explained at the corresponding documentation. **Remember: `.bind` returns a function!**

To keep it simple, I'll explain how to use `.bind` for a fixed number of arguments, say two. Then, the following have the same effect:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, 2, 3);
Math.max.bind(Math, 2, 3)();
```

And

```
Math.max.apply(Math, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Math.max.bind(Math, 2, 3)(4, 5);
```

If you've even glanced at the documentation, you'll certainly understand the first form. The second form is trickier though. It works *in this case*, because the position of an argument in `Math.max` is not relevant. The maximum value of *all* arguments is considered, where all arguments are treated identically.

Now, here follows an example with a custom function:

```
function echoMe(name, age) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name + '. Your age is ' + age);
    console.log('this is ', this);
}
echoMe('Rob', '19');
// "Hello Rob. Your age is 19"
// "this is [object DOMWindow]"  (non-strict mode)
var echoYou = echoMe.bind(null, "Oops");
echoYou("Peter", "19");
// "Hello Oops. Your age is Peter"
// "this is null"
```

Because the position of arguments is significant in this case, the last example showed something weird. Indeed, the first argument is **bound to "Oops"** by the `.bind` method. The arguments passed to the *bound function* `echoYou` are appended to the arguments list. Additionally, you notice that the context `this` was changed to `null`.

Interesting.. Let's try to change the context using `.apply`:

```
function printThisFood() {
    console.log("this.food is " + this.food);
}
printThisFood.apply({food: "Fish"});
// "this.food is fish"
var locked = printThisFood.bind({food: "Strong"});
locked.apply({food: "Weak"});
// "This.food is Strong"
```

As you can see, `this.food` still points to method from the context as defined through `.bind`!

---

So, we know how to lock the context of a function, as well as passing an arbitrary number of *fixed* arguments to a function. This can be applied to constructors, resulting in the function which I presented on top of the answer. To verify that it works as expected:

```
function Constructor() {
    console.log(this instanceof Constructor); // true
    console.log(this, arguments);             // Convince yourself via console
}
var bindArgs = [Constructor.prototype].concat([1, 2]);
// is equal to [Constructor.prototype, 1, 2]

var BoundConstructor = Function.prototype.bind.apply(Constructor, bindArgs);
var instance = new BoundConstructor();

// Eliminated intermediate variable, and put on one line
var instance = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Constructor, bindArgs));
```

Note: I omitted parentheses `()` in the one-liner, because constructors can be initialized without these. `new Image` and `new Image()` are behaving identically.
To immediately read a property (or invoke a method) from the constructed method, you can either wrap the whole expression in parentheses or append `()` to remove ambiguity:

```
(new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Constructor, bindArgs))).method()
new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Constructor, bindArgs))().method();
```

Note 2: It still holds that additional arguments are appended to the argument list. This property can also be used to "preset" the first arguments of a given constructor:

```
function Stupid(obvious1, obvious2, foo) { this.interesting = foo; }
Stupid.prototype.onlymethod = function() { return this.interesting};
var saveKeyStroke = Function.prototype.bind.call(Stupid, Stupid.prototype, 1, 2);
// Or, equivalent:
//var saveKeyStroke=Function.prototype.bind.apply(Stupid,[Stupid.prototype,1,2]);

new saveKeyStroke('Fourth argument').onlymethod(); // "Fourth argument"
new saveKeyStroke().onlymethod(); // undefined
(new saveKeyStroke).onlymethod(); // undefined
```

Comment: Note: the `bind` method is not supported in IE8 and earlier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

Apply is safe,but it would not return any instance of `bleh.Thinggy`.
If you want instance of `bleh.Thinggy` then you have to create it before using bleh.Thinggy.apply.

code:

```
var m = new bleh.Thinggy; // m is instance of  bleh.Thinggy.
        bleh.Thinggy.apply(m, args);
        ... use m as instance of bleh.Thinggy.apply
```

Comment: That would call the constructor function twice, first with zero parameters, then with the parameters in `args`.

Comment: yes, but m will behave as a instance of bleh.Thinggy. I dont think there is any other way to get instance.

Comment: @Shusl Is there a chance that the first instantiation could cause some problems for the second one?

Comment: @megazord. I don't think so. You can use it if you can create an instance of bleh.Thinggy with no argument.